# How can I center my div that is in another div?

Tags: html, css, .net

My inner div has this CSS:

```
.square3 {
  border:solid 1px #008CBA;
  background-color:white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.square3:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

My outer div has this CSS:

```
.monthInfo{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

I tried giving my outer text-align:center, and the inner margin:0 auto, but that didn't work. The inner div is all the way to the left of the page. I want it to stay in the center.

Comment: btw, using `float` makes an element `display: block` so if you have `float` on an element, `display: inline-block` won't do anything and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align: center` on the parent will work if you remove `float: left` from the child.

```css
.square3 {
  border:solid 1px #008CBA;
  background-color:white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.square3:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.monthInfo{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index:1000;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="monthInfo">
  <div class="square3">
  </div>
</div>
```